# Unhandled exception check in C++

Tags: c++, exception

Is there any way in C++ to get a compile-time error or warning if an exception is unhandled? For example, consider this Java code snippet:

```
public void f()
{
    g();  // <-- Java compiler reports "Unhandled exception" error here.
}

public void g() throws Exception
{
}
```

Can g++ or MSVC do something similar? Or is there any external code parsing tool which can do this? I suppose one could programmatically extend the C++ parser of Eclipse CDT to achieve this, but... are there easier solutions?

Comment: One thing I like about Symbian C++ is the naming convention of ending function names with 'L' when the function contains code that can throw an exception/'Leave'. You know exactly what can happen without constantly referring to the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply, no. C++ exception specifications have a different meaning to Java's exception specifications and they are now deprecated so you should consider avoiding them if possible.

In C++, the checks requested by exception specification are enforced only at runtime. In C++, if a function violates its exception specification the the "unexpected" handler is called. It is not a compile time error to call a function that can potentially throw an arbitrary exception from a function with an exception specification.

ISO/IEC 14882:2011 15.4 [except.spec] / 11:

> An implementation shall not reject an expression merely because when executed it throws or might throw an exception that the containing function does not allow.

Comment: Well I supposed there would be no "standard" way to do this. I was just wondering if there existed at least some external parser for this, since it can be useful to find potential errors within (already existing) code.

Comment: @emkey08: Again, no. It's impractical to enforce. Because - unlike Java - any function can call any other function regardless of the exception that it can potentially throw (even if the calling function has an exception specification) it's impractial - if not impossible - to check statically whether an exception specification will be violated. (E.g. Consider a library function with no available source.) Further more, as whether an exception is actually thrown may depend on the run time environment or input it's not even valid to attempt to do a compile time check.

Comment: I actually thought of this as a possible warning the compiler could optionally generate, just to draw the programmer's eyes to potentially buggy code. Something like the "comparison between signed and unsigned values" warning - something which can help in some situations to find potential problems faster.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. There are no checked exceptions in C++. You can try to use an external tool, but TBH I've never seen anyone do that. Just document the interfaces properly.